# MySQL query to search for MATCH in 3 columns?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I created a FULLTEXT Index for columns: `City, Group and Text` called `city_group_text_comparator`

How do I do a simple query to look up a string on all 3?

I tried this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE MATCH (City, `Group`, Text) AGAINST ('$search') LIMIT $limit_posts OFFSET $first_post");
```

How does it order the results?

Thanks

Comment: lol I managed to do it... mmm do I answer it myself?

Comment: Yes, that's the right thing to do. Answer the question and accept it. StackOverflow's goal is to build a repository of answers to specific programming questions. You would not further than goal by failing to add the answer, even if it's your own question. The next person to have the same question and finds this page will thank you for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My example was actually right:

Adding inverted quotes around Group did the trick:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE MATCH (City, `Group`, Text) AGAINST ('$search') LIMIT $limit_posts OFFSET $first_post");
```

Probably it's a reserved value for MySQL, honestly don't know why, but nevertheless it works this way.

Comment: `GROUP BY` is a clause in `SELECT` queries. That's why it's a reserved word.